# C++11 std::thread join to main thread in a separate method

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following code:

```
void do_join(std::thread& t)
{
    t.join();
}

void join_all(std::vector<std::thread>& v)
{
    std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),do_join);
}

int main()
{         
    std::vector<std::thread> myThreads;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {

        myThreads.push_back(std::thread(threadMethod));

    }


    join_all(myThreads);
}
```

The goal is to create multiple threads in a loop, add them to a thread *vector* and then iterating through the vector join them to the **main** thread.

The problem here is that when my *do_join* method executes for the first time it joins the thread and waits, not joining any other threads from a *vector*. That is because my threads are using some conditional variables and waiting for some other tasks to complete. Seems like that *do_join* method is waiting for just joined thread to complete.

The same thing happens if I try to do *for_each* directly in the *main* function.

The idea is to be able to join all these threads to the **main** thread, not to that let's say *do_join*'s method thread which I suppose happened here. I could of course join and create them separately, because actually I don't need them to be in a vector (the number of threads is known from the beginning), but I need a vector because each thread in my application is actually created using different method's parameters which I did not included in that sample code. I just do not want a new line for every single thread being created and joined.

Thank you for any help!

Edit:
Maybe worth mentioning is that I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: think this is the expected behavior since it's the same thread (main) that waits for the child threads.

Comment: In that case it seems that joining the treads does not join them to the main thread. If it was like that all the treads in a vector would be joined, but that methods joins only one thread and then waits forever. When I do the same in the main method, but creating each thread separately (not using vector) and joining them separately, everything goes fine and all the treads are joined.
Here it seems that these threads are joined to that do_join method, and that method after joining the thread waits until it finishes. This should be main method waiting for them, not do_join method.

Comment: If a `t.join()` doesn't return it means the thread isn't finished, and you're not going to be joining the other threads until that one does so. An MCVE would look [something like this](http://pastebin.com/zP1iLd2M). if it works, then your problem is whatever is keeping your threads from returning or someone, somewhere, is futzing with your vector. Your threads aren't modifying the vector on exit, *right* ??

Comment: for empty threadMethod works.
void threadMethod(){
}

void do_join(std::thread& t)
{
    std::thread::id  tid =  t.get_id(); 
    t.join();
    cout << tid <<  " joined." << endl;
    
}

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c65c3786bcb868f1

Comment: I’m not sure what you are talking about at all. You are saying something about “do_join’s method thread”. Are you actually running `do_join` in a separate thread, not in main?

Comment: Of course it works for empty threadMethod. As I said, my threads are using some conditional variables and that is normal that after joining them they are not finished. But when I do something like that -> http://pastebin.com/eKDZ71TC it works perfectly fine, all threads are joined and then the **main** method is not finished before all of these threads finish.

Comment: To simplify: what I would like to do is instead of initializing my threads like that -> http://pastebin.com/eKDZ71TC I would like to create them and put into a vector and then join them all. Just to have a code equivalent to that one, but not having to write a new line for each thread's creation and then for each thread's joining.

Comment: "after joining them they are not finished" ... err, what? Calling `t.join()` means "wait for the thread `t` to finish, and then return from the call to `join()`." So it will wait for the first one, then for the second one (or return immediately if that's finished in the meantime), then for the next one etc."

Comment: "that is normal that after joining them they are not finished." - um. they better be. that's the point of `join`. It isn't returning until each joinable thread it is invoked on *is* **finished**.

Comment: First thread in the vector will be joined first, then the second etc. etc. If the first is not completed, but all others are done, then also the join method appears to be hanging. Check this ... https://gist.github.com/nipuntalukdar/939f271a45b5c947c1e6

Comment: Really joining the thread waits "in the place" of join method until the thread executes and finishes? So what would you say for my code which I showed (http://pastebin.com/eKDZ71TC) ? After first join the second thread is joined, but first thread is not finished. All threads are joined, but they are not finished, these threads will finish after some other threads which I create later finish their job (this is ensured by a condition variable). From what I undestood by joining the thread in the **main** method it will not allow the **main** method to finish before all joined threads are finished

Comment: @ikS11. do you mean the join wait forever (?), and all threads do nothing(?), if you use the loop and otherwise not?.

Comment: @ikS11 "Thread1.join(); // method's execution does not stop here! All threads are joined":? but thread execution is stopped. method may be executed by other threads.

Comment: once a join commences, the current thread is suspended until the thread being joined *finishes*. then the current thread can resume and join the next thread, thus suspending *again* until that thread *finishes*, etc. If it can be put any clearer than that, I don't see how. It almost sounds like you're looking for a synonymous activity similar to win32's `WaitForMultipleObjects` with `bWaitAll=TRUE`, which just keeps waiting until they're all signalled in no specific order. No such construct exists in `std::thread` programming.

Comment: Show minimum code to reproduce the issue in the question itself, this is unanswerable without it.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, the reason was I was putting joins before other threads needed to be created first were created. So to sum up, when we'd like to create threads and them wait for all of them to finish before **main()** method finished, we of course have to put all the joins in the end of **main** method.
Thank all of you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `join` method *by definition* blocks current thread until the one you are trying to join is done:

> Blocks the current thread until the thread identified by `*this`
>   finishes its execution.

([From here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join))

That is, it’s the *purpose* of `join` to block its thread until the other one finishes. If you don’t want the thread to be blocked, then don’t use `join`.

You should ask yourself the question: what are you trying to achieve? If you want your main program to proceed only when all the other threads are done, then what you are doing now is right, you’ll have to wait for all the threads anyway. Otherwise you might need some way for other threads to signal the main one that they are done.

Comment: Ok, I will show some more code, I hope I explained everything clear enough in the code -> http://pastebin.com/6J89c3j6

Comment: Link updated, method names corrected.
The main idea of all this application is when the application starts all threads are started and using condition variables the wait for each other to complete some tasks. Then the other threads executes, notify other ones that they finhed so the other ones waiting can complete their tasks etc...

Comment: @ikS11 Your code looks fine, and the only thing you can do is replace creation and joining every thread on its own by similar `for` loops. The initial version of your code as seen in the question does this pretty well, so what’s the problem?

Comment: Actually it does not... :D. Going from that point: replacing these creations and joinings by some loops is everything I want to do. So... replacing that code with such a code: http://pastebin.com/XnrJ43qS does not work the same as the previous one. Now, when the first thread is joined, it is stuck in the **do_join** method and waits for that thread to finish. It will join only the first thread, but in the first version (http://pastebin.com/6J89c3j6) it joined all of the threads and then **main()** function waits until ALL of them finishes. That is the problem.

Comment: @ikS11 That simply *cannot be true.* `t.join()` does not return until the thread `t` is finished, *period.* There must be something in the code you haven't shown that doesn't work as you expect - perhaps the threads terminate before they start waiting, or there's a race condition, or... But `join()` does not mean "wait for the thread before you exit the current function," it means "wait for the thread before you return from the `join()` call."

Comment: @ikS11 You totally don’t understand what the `join` method does. Well, I agree, its name might be a little bit misleading, but there is no such thing as “joining” a thread (whatever you think this means). All the `join` method does is it _waits for the thread to finish_ and returns then. Nothing else.

Comment: Ok, I get what **join()** does. But I did not change anything in my code except of changing manual creations and joining the threads to create them in a vector and join in a **for_each** loop.
So how is that possible that in this code http://pastebin.com/6J89c3j6 at line 55. all these threads Thread1...Thread6 are not finished? What you said is that **join()** method waits for the thread to finish. But in the line 55. these threads are not finished, they are waiting for notification from condition variable (isReady.wait....) ...

Comment: @ikS11 We need to see the entire code to reproduce the issue; perhaps you have a race condition which manifests due to the different time it takes to put a `thread` into the `vector`. Or something else.

Comment: @ikS11 The code you linked is incomplete, in can’t be compiled, so you are obviously running different code, not that you show us. Now, if we pretend that the definition of `MyObject` is complete and you run exactly this code, then it gets stuck at line 49, as the thread `Thread1` is still executing its code (waiting on the variable). And it will be hanging on line 49 forever.

Comment: Guys, actually you're right :). My mistake is that after joining these threads I create another ones... <facepalm>. The concept is to create all threads in the beginning and then wait for ALL of them to finish, so I need to place all of my joins, which are actually only WAITING at the end of my code (at the end of **main** method). I did that and it works :). Thank you so much! I'm not a big fan of C/C++ :).

Comment: And actually it was normal that join was waiting forever, because the other threads which need to be started to change the status value and notify the "first" threads were... not created yet. Egh.. :).